# How can I disable an exposed dropdown menu if the previous exposed dropdown is not filled?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, drop-down-menu, dropdown

So I have a list of of 4 exposed dropdown menus and I want choosing an option to one of them to be disabled if the previous one does not have an option choosed so it is null.

I changed my layout to make them disabled from the beginning :

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/doctor_dropdown"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:hint="@string/choose_a_doctor"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_text_view_doctor_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="none"

        />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And then `onCreateView()`in the fragment code I put the following:

```
 if(!autocomplete_text_view_hospital_dropdown.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty()){

            doctor_dropdown.isEnabled

        }
```

where hospital_dropdown is the previous dropdown which I need to be not empty in order for the doctor_dropdown to be enabled.
But the app crashes as soon as I click the relevant fragment.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: what crash are you seeing? Can you post the stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: Hello, I dont see a crush anymore as I moved the "if" from onCreateView() to onResume() but it still doesn't function as it should. I can choose interact with the first dropdown but once I choose the next one does not become available